# How to navigate to another page with a smooth scroll on a specific id with react router and react scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

i am trying to make navBar that navigate to another page and scroll down to some id on this page

this is the navBar component for my protofolio whih have  3 links the `Projects` should go to `Home` and then scroll down to `projects` id in the Project section

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "../../images/logo.png";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Scroll from "react-scroll";
import "./NavBar.css";
const ScrollLink = Scroll.Link;

class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="NavBar">
        <Link to="/" className="logo-container">
          <img className="logo" src={logo} alt="Mahboub logo"></img>
        </Link>
        <div className="Nav-links">

          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          <ScrollLink
            className="navy"
            smooth={true}
            duration={500}
            to="projects"
          >
            projects
          </ScrollLink>

          <Link to="/">Contacts</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default NavBar;
```

here is the prjects component for project section  in home page

```
function Projects() {
  return (
    <div className="Home-Projects">
      <Element id="projects">
        <h1>Projects</h1>
      </Element>
      <div className="Projects-container">
        <ProjectElement />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 24):

If "duration" parameter isn't of great importance for you and you have no problems with Hooks, I'd like to suggest solution as follows.

- You get rid of Scroll component and use plain Link from RR in your NavBar like so

  ```
  <Link to="/#projects">projects</Link>
  ```
- Since RR v5.1 [Hooks was introduced](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/). There is useLocation hook among them. Insert that hook at the very beginning of your Projects component like so:

  ```
  function Projects() {
  const location = useLocation()
  ...
  ```

When you hit Link from p.1, you get new location object of the form

```
    location = {
        ...
        pathname:"/",
        ...
        hash: "#projects"
    }
```

- Call `useEffect` hook after `useLocation` like so:

```
    useEffect(()=> {
            if (location.hash) {
                let elem = document.getElementById(location.hash.slice(1))
                if (elem) {
                    elem.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
                }
            } else {
            window.scrollTo({top:0,left:0, behavior: "smooth"})
            }
    }, [location,])
```

And thats it. As you can see, if there is no hash in your url, your page would scroll to the top. Use `[locaton,]` as `useEffect` dependency prevents form scrolling when your page component rerenders not because of location changes.

Comment: This is a great answer! Works well. Thank you

Comment: This worked perfectly. but I recommend adding html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
} to make the scroll smoother

Comment: So simple, yet so effective. Thanks

Comment: great inspiration, thank you

Answer (score 4):

I just add this in the index.css

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

and this

```
 <ScrollLink
            className="navy"
            smooth={true}
            duration={500}
            to="projects"
          >
            projects
 </ScrollLink>
```

became

```
 <a href="/#projects">Projects</a>
```

this was so fast and simple and worked prefectly

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing, but its not working with these

Comment: this works, but it takes some time to scroll, I did the @DmitriyBelovol solution, and turn out using javascript to do this was a faster performance, on the other hand, your solution is great and a lot shorter

Answer (score 2):

For next.js

```
//https://yourdomain.com/page?scroll=scroll_here <---

import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Flex } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
export default function DecisionAreaFlex(props) {
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('router query', router.query.scroll);
    if (router.query.scroll) {
      let elem = document.getElementById(router.query.scroll);
      if (elem) {
        elem.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
      }
    } else {
      window.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
  }, [router]);

  return (
    <Flex
      alignSelf="center"
      justifyContent="center"
      alignItems="center"
      mt="15px"
      id={'scroll_here'} // <--- 
    >
      {props.children}
    </Flex>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a query param called `anchor`, and with that I can control the scroll based on the `useEffect`.

The link: `/about?anchor=capabilities`

The code on the page which should have the smooth scroll:

```
const router = useRouter();

useEffect(()=> {
  if (router?.query?.anchor) {
    let elem = document.getElementById(router?.query?.anchor)
    if (elem) {
      elem.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
    }
  }
}, [router?.query?.anchor])
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the simplest solution for **scrolling to an id from another page**.
use this code on the page where you have sections with any xyz id.
now on the other pages use simple **NavLink** from react-router-dom having "to" attribute like this to="/#xy"

```
 let location = useLocation()
   useEffect(()=> {
    if (location.hash) {
      let elem = document.getElementById(location.hash.slice(1))
      if(elem) {
        elem.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
               }          
        } else {
  window.scrollTo({top:0,left:0, behavior: "smooth"})
                }
    }, [location,])
```