# React Router and scrollTo behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to get the following functionality with React Router when I click on a link.

Let's say this is my current location: `page/1`

If I'm currently on page 1 (`page/1`) and I click on a link that takes me to `page/1`, **I would like the browser to scroll to the top of the page** using something like window.scrollTo with a smooth behaviour.

If I'm on any other page, for example `page/2`, I would like the **standard Redirect behaviour**.

What would be the best way to accomplish something like this? I thought about something like:

`if current location === page I'm trying to access -> scroll behaviour`

`else Redirect`

I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this? For example, always redirect and scroll to top, so even if I click on the same page it would scroll anyways

Comment: Please do check this.......... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61779236/how-to-navigate-to-another-page-with-a-smooth-scroll-on-a-specific-id-with-react#answer-61784812

Answer (score 0):

You can you a library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll

```
// ES6 Imports
import { animateScroll as scroll } from 'react-scroll'

var Section = React.createClass({

  scrollToTop: function() {
    scroll.scrollToTop();
  },

  handleSetActive: function(to) {
    console.log(to);
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link activeClass="active" to="test1" spy={true} smooth={true} offset={50} duration={500} onSetActive={this.handleSetActive}>
          Test 1
        </Link>
        <Link activeClass="active" to="test1" spy={true} smooth={true} offset={50} duration={500} delay={1000}>
          Test 2 (delay)
        </Link>
        <Link className="test6" to="anchor" spy={true} smooth={true} duration={500}>
          Test 6 (anchor)
        </Link>
        <Button activeClass="active" className="btn" type="submit" value="Test 2" to="test2" spy={true} smooth={true} offset={50} duration={500} >
          Test 2
        </Button>

        <Element name="test1" className="element">
          test 1
        </Element>

        <Element name="test2" className="element">
          test 2
        </Element>

        <div id="anchor" className="element">
          test 6 (anchor)
        </div>


        <Link to="firstInsideContainer" containerId="containerElement">
          Go to first element inside container
        </Link>

        <Link to="secondInsideContainer" containerId="containerElement">
          Go to second element inside container
        </Link>
        <div className="element" id="containerElement">
          <Element name="firstInsideContainer">
            first element inside container
          </Element>

          <Element name="secondInsideContainer">
            second element inside container
          </Element>
        </div>

        <a onClick={this.scrollToTop}>To the top!</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(
  <Section />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

Comment: I think it's a bit unecessary to import a 100kb library for a simple use case like this. Surely there must be an easier way of doing this?